# Load resistance of this circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, npn

[image]

I want to make sure I understood this correctly .
If I want to measure the load resistance of this circuit, is it between (A - G) ?

Comment: It's wherever you want it to be - you define where it needs to be (and also your bandwidth of interest).

Comment: I would not call it "load resistance"...it is the "source resistance" - and the load resistance is connected to the ouput node A.